# My html will not connect to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML is not connecting to my javascript. I have run it in debugger several times and no matter what I have tried my HTML has not connected to my js. I have done this small piece of coding a fair few times now and am stumped at why it is not working.

Here is where my HTML is supposed to connect to my javascript.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>One Down</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="termFourMajorProject.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="term 4 major project.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="two_decks.png"/>
</head>
```

Please, can you tell me why my HTML is not connect ing to my javascript? (ignore the jQuery document)

Comment: What do you mean "connect to my JS"? I think you need to fully explain what the problem is.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Why do you *think* something is wrong with this code?

Comment: are you saying that `termFourMajorProject.js` isn't loading into the page? is this file in the same "folder" as the html page? what are you using for http server?

Comment: your js file is called `"termFourMajorProject.js"` and your css file is called `"term 4 major project.css"` - it's odd you have one with and another without spaces

Comment: open your webpage and press `Ctrl+F5`

Comment: Check for errors in console. You must be placing js files elsewhere and html file at different location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your. js file is in the same directory where your html file is present. And also you should add html tag to your code